# how to rotate log files by filesize?

Tags: logging, logrotate, access-log, log-rotation

**ATTENTION: there are many articles about rotating log files by date/time. But i want to rotate log files by filesize. Is it possible?**

---

i have apache access_log file which is growing largely and taking up the entire server free space after 2/3 weeks. As a result my server sees no more free space after 2/3 weeks and i have to manually clean up the log file every 2/3 weeks.

Here is what i want to do:

- rotate the access_log file at every 5 MegaBytes.
- don't want to have more than 20 such files.
- if we reach 20x5MB files, then should remove the oldest log file first before creating a new rotation

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "size" parameter in the logrotate.conf to fix the max file size of the log file
and the "rotate" option fix the number of rotation thus
you can put:

```
/var/log/apache2/access_log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    size 5M
    rotate 20
    create 0600 apache2 apache2
}
```

as usual, **man logrotate** is your best friend

Comment: shouldn't we use daily in the configuration? I have the same requirement and I want once the size of the file reached 5M my file splite.